# Adding quantity of all items in cart and not just 1 number per specific id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, shopping-cart

So I've got my cart up and running. The total price reflects all items in the cart, but the only issue is you can't tell how many total items there are. If I have one of an item that's fine since the cart icon shows 1. However if I for example put two of the same item in the cart it will still show 1 despite the total price in the cart reflecting 2 items. How can I get the cart number to relfect the TOTAL number of items. I'm new to using Context, and so maybe I've just taken an obvious misstep? Thanks!

Here is my context code for my adding, removing, and stuff.

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const CartContext = createContext();

export function CartProvider({children}) {

    const [ cartItems, setCartItems ] = useState([]);

    const addToCart = (item) => {
        const isItemInCart = cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id); // Check if the item is already in the cart

        if (isItemInCart) {
            setCartItems(
                cartItems.map((cartItem) => // if the item is already in the cart, increase the quantity of the item
                cartItem.id === item.id
                ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
                : cartItem // otherwise, return the cart item
                )
            );
        } else {
            setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...item, quantity: 1}]); // if the item is not in the cart, add the item to the cart
        }
    };

    const removeFromCart = (item) => {
        const isItemInCart = cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);

        if (isItemInCart.quantity === 1) {
            setCartItems(cartItems.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== item.id)); // if the quantity of the item is 1, remove the item from the cart
        } else {
            setCartItems(
                cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
                  cartItem.id === item.id
                    ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity - 1 } // if the quantity of the item is greater than 1, decrease the quantity of the item
                    : cartItem
                    )
            )
        }
    };

    const clearCart = () => {
        setCartItems([]); // set the cart items to an empty array
    };

    const getCartTotal = () => {
        return cartItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0); // calculate the total price of the items in the cart
    };

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart, getCartTotal}}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )

}


export default CartContext;
```

Here is my page for adding stuff to the cart.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import data from './data.json';
import { CartContext } from '../Context/CartContext'

export default function Foodinfo() {

    const { addToCart } = useContext(CartContext)
    const params = useParams();
    const [item, setItem] = useState(null);

  
    useEffect(() => {

        // Parse the id from the URL params to an integer type
        const idFromUrl = parseInt(params.id, 10);

        // Find the item in the data array that matches the id from the URL
        const foundItem = data.find((d) => d.id === idFromUrl);
      
        // Set the found item in the state
        setItem(foundItem);
    }, [params.id]);
  
    return (
        <div>
            {/* Check if item exists before trying to access its properties */}
            {item ? (
                <div className="flex flex-wrap border-4 border-red-500 rounded-[25px] bg-white mt-12 md:mt-24 mx-auto justify-center max-w-[80%] md:max-w-[50%]">
                    <h2 className="my-auto py-5 mx-auto md:text-2xl">{item.title}</h2>
                    <img src={item.pic} alt={item.name} className="w-[400px] h-[300px] mx-auto pb-5 md:mt-5" />
                  <div className="flex flex-col mx-auto">  
                    <h1 className="font-bold text-center md:my-auto md:text-2xl">Item Info</h1>
                    <p className="my-3 mx-auto text-center md:my-auto md:text-2xl">{item.info}</p>      
                    <p className="text-center mb-3 md:my-auto md:text-2xl md:pb-3"><strong>Calories:</strong> {item.calories}</p>            
                    <button onClick={() => addToCart(item)} className="mx-auto border-4 border-red-600 bg-red-300 rounded-xl mb-3 w-[150px] hover:bg-red-500 hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75 font-semibold">Add To Cart</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is my Cart page.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../Context/CartContext'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Cart() {

  const { cartItems, removeFromCart, getCartTotal, clearCart } = useContext(CartContext);

  // Cart price and tax price
  const itemsPrice = {getCartTotal}
  const taxPrice = itemsPrice * 0.14;
  const totalPrice = itemsPrice + taxPrice

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-white h-16 mb-7 flex items-center">
        <h1 className="text-2xl mx-auto font-semibold">Checkout Cart</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center mx-auto flex-col border-4 border-red-500 rounded-[25px] bg-white max-w-[500px]">
        {cartItems.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="border-2 border-red-500 rounded-[25px] mx-7 my-7">
            <img className="w-[400px] h-[300px] rounded-[25px] px-2 py-2 mx-auto" src={item.pic} alt={item.title} />
            <div className="text-center">
              <p>{item.title}</p>
              <p>{item.price}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex">
              <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(item)} className="font-semibold mx-auto border-2 text-center border-red-600 bg-red-300 rounded-xl mb-3 w-[150px] hover:bg-red-500 hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75">Remove From Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        {
          cartItems.length > 0 ? (
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-between items-center">
          <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">Total: ${getCartTotal()}</h1>
          <button 
            onClick={() => alert('I wish you could!')}
            className="py-2 font-bold border-2 text-center border-red-600 bg-red-300 rounded-xl mb-3 w-[150px] hover:bg-red-500 hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75">Checkout!</button>
          <button
            className="mt-10 px-4 border-2 text-center border-red-600 bg-red-300 rounded-xl mb-3 w-[120px] hover:bg-red-500 hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75"
            onClick={() => {
              clearCart()
            }}
          >
            Clear cart
          </button>
        </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="flex flex-col mx-auto">
              <h1 className="text-lg font-bold text-center my-3">Your cart is empty</h1>
              <Link to="/">
                <button className="border-2 font-semibold text-center border-red-600 bg-red-300 rounded-xl mb-3 w-[150px] hover:bg-red-500 hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75">Return to Menu</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then finally here is my Navbar that contains the cart icon and the number showing the number of cart items.

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import {AiOutlineClose, AiOutlineMenu} from 'react-icons/ai'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { CartContext } from '../Context/CartContext'

const Navbar = () => {

    const { cartItems } = useContext(CartContext)
    const [nav, setNav] = useState(true)
    const [ showModal, setShowModal ] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => {
        setShowModal(!showModal)
    }

    const handleNav = () => {
        setNav(!nav)
    }

  return (
    <nav className="h-20 mx-auto p-4 font-bold bg-red-200">
        <div className="menubar">
            {!nav ? <AiOutlineClose size={20} className="text-white" /> : <AiOutlineMenu onClick={handleNav} size={20} color="red" className="hover:cursor-pointer" />}
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold m-auto">Brian's Burger Bash</h1>
            <div className="flex">
              <Link to="/cart"><img src="/bag.jpg" className="bag relative" /></Link>
              {!showModal && <button className='absolute bg-[#FF0000] rounded-full text-white w-6 right-2 bottom-4'
                  onClick={toggle}
              >{cartItems.length}</button>}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className={!nav ? "fixed left-0 top-0 w-[435px] bg-red-600 text-white h-full border-r border-r-gray-90 ease-in-out duration-200" : "ease-in-out duration-200 fixed left-[-100%]"}>
          <div className="flex">
            <h1 className="w-full text-3xl font-bold text-black-500 m-3 mt-4 ml-14">BBB's</h1>
            <button onClick={handleNav} className="mr-14 mt-4">X</button>
          </div>
          <ul className="uppercase p-7 text-center text-2xl">
            <Link to='/'><li onClick={handleNav} className="p-7 hover:underline decoration-solid decoration-black decoration-4">MENU</li></Link>
            <Link to='locations'><li onClick={handleNav} className="p-7 hover:underline decoration-solid decoration-black decoration-4">LOCATIONS</li></Link>
            <Link to='contact'><li onClick={handleNav} className="p-7 hover:underline decoration-solid decoration-black decoration-4">CONTACT US</li></Link>
            <Link to='careers'><li onClick={handleNav} className="p-7 hover:underline decoration-solid decoration-black decoration-4">CAREERS</li></Link>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let totalCartItems = 0;

cartItems.forEach((item)=>{ 
  totalCartItems = totalCartItems + item.quantity;
})
```

> you need to check quantity of all items in your cart and add them to
> get total cartItems.